# Blender reverses X-axis when exporting Z-forward

Tags: export, coordinates

When I export object as it is - in Right handed system, everything exports fine. When I try to export to use object in Left handed system, I set Z-forward when exporting and now interesting things happen. It flips Z axis as would every sane person expect, however it also flips X-axis.

Comment: Which exporter? You may find that it isn't 'flipping' - it is rotating, to change the Z-axis it may also change X by using Y as the centre of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot export to left-handed system in Blender (not with default 'orientation toolkit' used by most exporters at least). As @sambler said, this only performs rotations (and uniform scaling).

Note that switching something as complex as a Blender scene from right to left handed coordinates is a nice little nightmare (think about animations, parenting, etc.), afaik nobody ever seriously worked on this topic so far.